# Using a Nested For Loop to create a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I am trying to create a new column using information from a list and also an existing column.
I created a nested FOR LOOP to go through the existing and the list simultaneously, checking if the information in the list is the same as that of the existing column, if Yes, then it should perform a task, if no then do something different.

But I keep getting the error below:

```
ValueError: Length of values (2636) does not match length of index (659)
```

The IF statement works fine, but the Else aspect is what is generating more information and causing the length of the values to increase.

Below is my code, please i need help on this.

> 

```
directcustomers = ["Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct","Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct","Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct","Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct"]
direct_broker = []
for agent in monthinviewlist.AGENT_NAME:
  for name in directcustomers:
>     if agent == name:
>         direct_broker.append("Direct")
>     else:
>         direct_broker.append("Broker")
>         pass
> 
> monthinviewlist["Direct/Broker"] = direct_broker
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have a nested for loop, so if your `monthviewlist` has length `659`, and your `directcustomers` list has a length of `4`, then the total length of your `direct_broker` list is indeed `2636` (4*659) which is far larger than your original `monthviewlist`. Did you intend to only create 1 value per row, or do you wish to duplicate your rows to fit the new list?

Comment: Maybe your intention was to do something like `if agent in directcustomers: direct_brokers.append("direct") else direct_brokers.append("broker")` ? That way you only have one value per row and you can append the column.

Comment: @SpaceBurger i am trying to duplicate my rows to fit the new list using particular key words "Direct" & "Broker".

Answer (score 0):

Let us say we have the following parameters :

```py
>>> monthinviewlist
                        AGENT_NAME
0   Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct
1  Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct
2  Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct
3  Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct
4                           OtherA
5                           OtherB
6                           OtherC

>>> directcustomers
["Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct","Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct","Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct","Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct"]
```

In that case, your current nested loops output something like:

```py
>>> direct_broker
["direct", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "direct", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "direct", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "direct", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker", "broker"]

>>> len(direct_broker)
28
```

Here we have `len(direct_broker) == 28 == len(monthviewlist) * len(directcustomers)`. The problem you have is when you try to copy the content of this 28 elements array to a 7 elements table column. If it the intention was to duplicate your values, then you need to copy the agent names multiple times as well :

```py
ext_monthinviewlist = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["AGENT_NAME", "Direct/Broker"])
ext_agent_names = []
direct_or_broker = []

for agent in monthinviewlist.AGENT_NAME:
  ext_agent_names += [agent for _ in range(len(directcustomers))] # keep 4 times the same name
  for name in directcustomers: # add "broker" or "direct" 4 times
    if agent == name:
      direct_or_broker.append("Direct")
    else:
      direct_or_broker.append("Broker")

ext_monthinviewlist["AGENT_NAME"] = ext_agent_names
ext_monthinviewlist["Direct/Broker"] = direct_or_broker
```

That will output :

```py
>>> ext_monthinviewlist
                         AGENT_NAME Direct/Broker
0    Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct        direct
1    Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct        broker
2    Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct        broker
3    Old Mutual Abuja Branch Direct        broker
4   Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct        broker
5   Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct        direct
6   Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct        broker
7   Old Mutual Lagos Branch  Direct        broker
8   Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct        broker
9   Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct        broker
10  Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct        direct
11  Old Mutual Rivers Branch Direct        broker
12  Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct        broker
13  Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct        broker
14  Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct        broker
15  Old Mutual Ibadan Branch Direct        direct
16                           OtherA        broker
17                           OtherA        broker
18                           OtherA        broker
19                           OtherA        broker
20                           OtherB        broker
21                           OtherB        broker
22                           OtherB        broker
23                           OtherB        broker
24                           OtherC        broker
25                           OtherC        broker
26                           OtherC        broker
27                           OtherC        broker
```